# Can't push git updates & run Unix commands when connecting via SSH

Tags: centos, ssh, vps, java, git

I have installed java 8 on my bluehost VPS. I have followed http://tecadmin.net/install-java-8-on-centos-rhel-and-fedora/
instructions .

In order to add directories to `PATH` variable I have added

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_45
JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/jre
```

to `etc/environment` file.

After that I can't push upgrades to my git repository and when I login via ssh I can't run unix command.

My server OS is **CentOS** and its **64bit**

**EDIT :**

---

**Error shown in git :**

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags origin master:master
Pushing to root@162.144.42.157:/home/darmanjo/darmanjoo.git

bash: git-receive-pack: command not found

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**SSH Problem :**

```
login as: root
root@162.144.42.157's password:
Last login: Tue Apr 21 15:26:53 2015 from 109-110-182-162-dynamic.shabdiznet.com
-bash: id: command not found
-bash: tty: command not found
root@server.darmanjoo.com [~]# ls
-bash: ls: command not found
root@server.darmanjoo.com [~]#
```

Also my `echo $PATH` shows :

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin:/root/bin
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: The way your question is written it sounds as if you COULD have performed these tasks BEFORE you made these changes to PATH. In particular, your use of "after that". Also, if you're logging into a unix (linux) system, what "unix command" are you referring to - ANY command? The shell built-ins? Anything BUT the shell built-ins?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I can't run unix command : ls. also I can't push my git upgrades , Error shown : bash: git-receive-pack: command not found fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Please see my edits. thanks.

Comment: VPS hoster limitation ? Ask there help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use variable expansion in /etc/environment (which is why you see an unexpanded `$PATH` in the output from `echo $PATH`). `/etc/environment` is read by the pam_env module not a shell script so just simple assignments.

You probably want to add this stuff to `/etc/profile` or add a file under `/etc/profile.d/`.

See https://serverfault.com/questions/165342/can-you-use-variables-when-editing-etc-environment-in-ubuntu-10-04 for more details.